# Аллерты на рестарт сервиса

Tags: python, devops, мониторинг, prometheus, fastapi

Подскажите, каким образом можно настроить аллерты на рестарт сервиса? Т.е. мне важно понимать, что если сервис рестартанул, то нужно лезть и смотреть, что случилось. Используем prometheus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Несколько возможных вариантов решений.

## Вариант 1

Сервис отдает в прометей метрику - время работы со старта, алерт ставится на малое значение этой метрики

## Вариант 2

На старте сервиса дёргать алерт

## Вариант 3

При старте сервиса отправлять запрос в ещё один сервис, который собирает эту информацию